# Android widget unresponsive after crash/won't update

Tags: android, crash, widget

I've been working on a widget for a while, and it usually works fine when I try to run it or update the code, even after a crash. However, every once in a while it seems to have a "major" crash and the widget becomes completely unresponsive afterwards. Even if I try to push new code to the phone it remains unresponsive after the update.

I've tried uninstalling the widget and reinstalling it, only to have the same thing occur. The only thing that seems to work is if I do a factory reset of the phone. After that, the widget works fine until I start changing the code and I run into another such crash. However, I'd like to not have to do a factory reset every few days.

Has this happened to anyone/does anyone know what might be the cause of this? Is there some data stored on the phone somewhere that prevents it from ever working again after the first crash?

Here's what the error log looked like:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.alienweed.test.HelloWidget:   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2058)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1098)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
```

Comment: Compulsory to add the crash log in such cases.

Comment: Ok I don't have it from earlier but I'll try to recreate the crash

Comment: Sorry that took so long, I finally remembered to trace the crash. It's up top in the original post now.

Comment: You need to check your cursor length before trying to access it.

Comment: Yeah, the problem I'm having now is that after a crash like this, I can no longer update the code on my droid. The widget becomes completely responsive and the only way I've found that I can push code after this happens is to do a factory reset. Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: have you tried on a different device? What error does it give when you try to install after the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the crash.

```
Cursor curs = db.query(params...);
/* check the cursor now */
if(curs.moveToFirst()) {  // `moveToFirst()` returns false if cursor is empty.
    // access the cursor.
}
```